# CherryPy Calling a function on session expiry

Tags: python, session, web-applications, cherrypy

I am using sessions in a webapp and want to have them call a function when they expire. I have read the documentation on sessions in cherryPy (http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/lib/sessions.html) and am unsure how to achieve this.

```
class MainApp(object):
    #CherryPy Configuration
    _cp_config = {'tools.encode.on': True, 
              'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8',
              'tools.sessions.on' : True,
              'tools.sessions.timeout' : 5 }

    def login(self,user):
        cherrypy.session['username'] = username

    def doThisWhenSessionExpires()
        db = sqlite3.connect('userData.db')
        db.execute('''UPDATE currentUser set active = "No" where ID=1''')
        db.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(root(), '/')
```

Is there a way to achieve this sort of functionality?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such trigger built-in. You'd have to inherit session class and reimplement [`clean_up` method](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py#L393-L414) your way. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: The idea was to have a backgroundTask updating a database based on if the user was online, I have since implemented my own sessions class so that it is not thread local and can be passed to the backgroundTask instead.

Comment: Why don't you use redis-based sessions with its expiration features? Personally, I don't see any need for having such background task at all.